# Mapstruct - Mapping customModel to it's string representation

Tags: mapstruct

I have following structures

```
Public void Student(){
   private string name;
   private int age;
}


Public void Class(){
   private string roomNo;
   private Student student; //Student Object
}

Public void School(){
   private string roomNo;
   private String student; //String student
}
```

I am trying to map these using map struct

```
@Mapping(source = "java(student.toString())", target = "student")
School mapClassToSchool(@NonNull Class class);
```

I am getting following error

```
error: No property named "java(student.toString())" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "student"?
    [javac]         @Mapping(source = "java(student.toString())", target = "student")
    [javac]                           ^
```

I tried to go through this https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/ but cant simple example for my usecase

Ho do i map `student` to its `string` representation

Edit: 1

is it possible to do

```
@Mapping(expression = new GSON().toJson(clazz.getStudent()), target = "student")
School mapClassToSchool(@NonNull Class class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use expressions then you have to use `Mapping#expression`. Whatever you define in the expression it will be set one to one in the generated code.

e.g.

```
@Mapping(expression = "java(clazz.getStudent().toString())", target = "student")
School mapClassToSchool(@NonNull Class clazz);
```

Another alternative is to also define a mapping method between `Student` and `String`, then you won't need to define a custom `@Mapping` for the student.

e.g

```
School mapClassToSchool(@NonNull Class clazz);

default String mapStudentToString(Student student) {
    return student != null ? student.toString() : null;
}
```

---

Just a note, `class` is a Java reserved word.

- This doesn't compile: `School mapClassToSchool(@NonNull Class class)`.
- Use `clazz` instead: `School mapClassToSchool(@NonNull Class clazz)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was copying the code from the answer and completely missed it.

Comment: Oh, I didnt notice the OP made such mistake. I include note about `class` to your answer. Have +1 :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. My code is just a representation/quick example .  i have one more doubt.   If i do this "default String mapStudentToString(Student student) {
    return student != null ? student.toString() : null;
}".  Will this conversion happens all the time  or conversion happens only for= "mapClassToSchool(@NonNull Class clazz)" because i have one more method in same class which does "mapOldClassToNewClass(Class clazz) here i dont want string representation conversion